# Explain how it is working and returning unique values | SQL

Tags: oracle

I have table called dummy which as some records in it.

In one of the forum I found this query but not able to decrypt how it is working

Can some one help me to understand it with some example or graphically

**Table structure**

```
create table 
(
   srno number,
   name varchar2(250)
);
```

**My code :**

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
    dummy a
WHERE
    1 = (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(1) as cnt 
        FROM
            dummy b
        WHERE
                a.srno = b.srno
            AND a.name = b.name
            AND a.rowid >= b.rowid
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
    dummy a
WHERE
    1 = (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(1) as cnt 
        FROM
            dummy b
        WHERE
                a.srno = b.srno
            AND a.name = b.name
            AND a.rowid >= b.rowid
    );
```

The subquery used in the `WHERE` clause is called a *correlated subquery*. It is "correlated" because the conditions in its `WHERE` clause correlate the subquery's records with the main queries records.

What it's finding are records in the same table that share a `srno` and `name` with the record in the main query BUT where the `rowid` is different. So it's saying "Select all records from `dummy` that share this `dummy` record's `srno` and `name` but aren't this exact record. Then it's taking a count of how many records fit that condition. If the count of records fitting that condition is 1, that means that there is only one other record in `dummy` that share the same `srno` and `name`, so go ahead and return the current record.

In essence it's finding records that have only a single duplicate in the same table by `srno` and `name`.